# "Undefined Keyword" issue in VSC editor, Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

OK, so I had my first Robot Framework project written for practice a few months ago, everything worked fine, and I did not open it for a while, then today, when I did, 99% of my keywords had the "Undefined Keyword" errors popping up. The only thing I can think of is installing the RIDE editor a few days ago, but again, I deleted it - nothing changed

Screenshot link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMyVj.png

Answer (score 1):

py -3.8 -m pip install robotframework-seleniumLibrary

This command resolved my issue. VSC did not read the Selenium Library

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot suggest that your Library is not getting loaded with your project. Try to re-validate the project or refresh the project to make that happen. Also, check Selenium version against your robotframework version. Refer more at - https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/ under Version section.